# How to project and sort mongo using complex function

Tags: mongodb

Assuming the following table schema

```
 Student(username,score,total)
```

Assuming I want to project and sort in a way like this:

```
select username, score, ((total - max(score, 0))/total) as final_total
from Student
order by final_total
```

How to achieve a similar thing in Mongo, assuming for a  collection like this:

```
...
{"username": "jhon", "score": 240, "total": 300}
...
{ "username": "jean", "score": 120, "total": 220}
...
```

Comment: What is `total` in `((total - max(score, 0))/total)`? **Field name** or **sum of score**?

Comment: @Ashh: `total` is a field name